# lit-html / LitElement with sass

Tags: javascript, css, sass, polymer

How would i go about using something like sass with lit-html / LitElement. Is it possible to do it without having to use an external css file (like ${SharedStyles} in the pwa-starter-kit) with a webpack plugin?
Trying to make the pwa-starter-kit to work with it without having to switch to weback or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I have made up a simple loader for Webpack for building Single File Component with the LitElement. You can use PostCSS for your styles: [lit-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lit-loader)

Hope it can help also for a personal custom implementation.